# Instance counts from list of text tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc, count, ravendb

I am using RavenDB and allowing a user to enter an item into the database with which they can associate textual tags. The class for the item is

```
public class TagItem
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public List<string> Tags { get; set;}
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What i would like to do is get an instance count for each individual tag in a selection of items from the document query. For instance

```
Bacon : 12
Fudge : 8
Marshmallow : 6
```

I am currently doing this by iterating through the items and incrementing the count for each tag but it doesn't seem to be a very elegant way of obtaining the results. I was wondering if anyone had a suggestion for a better way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

-- EDIT #1 --

**Matt**

I have tried to implement your suggestion of faceted search but I cant seem to figure out how to perform a selection using a subset of userIDs. I have created the index as the following

```
   public class Tag_Facets : AbstractIndexCreationTask<UserModel>
   {
    public Tag_Facets()
    {
        Map = locations => from user in users 
                           from tag in user.Tags
                           select new { Tag = tag.ToString().ToLower(), user.Id };
    }
   }
```

I have a List of UserIds that I would like to use to narrow this selection down before running the facet against it but none of the methods that I have tried want to compile. Can you provide me with an idea of what the Where clause would look like for this?

My FacetSetup is as follows

```
this.DocumentSession.Store(new FacetSetup { Id = "facets/TagFacets", Facets = new 
List<Facet> { new Facet { Name = "Tag" } } });
```

The query that i am trying to build is

```
var facetResults = this.DocumentSession.Query<LocationModel>("Tag/Facets")
                .Where(x => x.Id.Contains(new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" }))
                .ToFacets("facets/TagFacets");
```

which will not build because Contains doesn't accept List

I was hoping that you might be able to point me in the right direction on how I might accomplish this.

Also, thank you for your work on Faceted Search. It seems to be what I'm looking for to perform a lot of the queries that I need to run in RavenDB. Cheers!

-- EDIT #2 --

This is the SQL expression that I would use to achieve the results that I wanted.

```
SELECT t.Tag, COUNT(*) FROM UserTags t WHERE t.UserID in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') GROUP BY t.Tag
```

Comment: I should add, that my current method of performing this is to limit the TagItems to a List<TagItem> by a group of UserId's then iterating through them to achieve the count. Therefore, it is not a total count of the items with a specific tag, but a total of the selected subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to use [faceted search](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/faceted-search) and get the counts from that. It's a little bit more flexible than Map/Reduce as it allows you to specify a query when you get the counts.

Given an index like this:

```
    from question in docs
    from tag in question.Tags
    select new 
    { 
        question.CreatedOn, 
        Tag = tag
    }
```

You then define the facet ranges like this (using the default behaviour, which will look for every unique term for you)

```
    var facetSetupDoc = new FacetSetup 
        { 
            Id = "facets/TagFacets", 
            Facets = new List<Facet> { new Facet {Name = "Tag"} } 
        }
```

Finally you query it like this:

```
    var facetResults = s.Query<Question>("QuestionTags")
                .Where(x => x.CreatedOn >= new DateTime(2008, 5, 20))
                .ToFacets("facets/TagFacets");
```

Take a look at this [code sample](https://gist.github.com/1214297), it shows how to implement your exact scenario.

Comment: I didn't quite get it to work yet but that comes down to learning it. This does fit my criteria for what I need to do so thank you for pointing me in that direction.

Comment: @jamesamuir if you're still having problems, post a question (and code) on the google group at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ravendb

Answer (score 2):

If you need the tag count grouped by tag name, the RavenDB website has already an example:

http://ravendb.net/kb/2/creating-a-tag-cloud

Slightly modified Index:

```
public class Tags_Count : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Post, Tags_Count.ReduceResult>
{
    public class ReduceResult
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }

    public Tags_Count()
    {
        Map = posts => from post in posts
                       from tag in post.Tags
                       select new { Name = tag.ToString().ToLower(), Count = 1 };

        Reduce = results => from tagCount in results
                            group tagCount by tagCount.Name
                            into g
                            select new {Name = g.Key, Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count) };    
    }
}
```

Of course you need a condition to limit it to a certain "section".

Comment: looking into this approach, it appears that I am limited to a subselection using only Name or Count, not by a single (or group) of UserId's. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You can limit it to whatever you want, this is just a LINQ query. 1. step search the documents that you are interested in 2. step group by whatever you want and count the "1" from the map function, I think you don't fully understand it yet.

Comment: The problem that I am having is understanding how to limit it dynamically. If I have a list of UserIds, how would i go about limiting the ReduceResult by that list of Ids (or any dynamic data other than Name or Count for that matter) if I am only selecting Name and Count in that result?

Comment: @jamesauir you can't change Map/Reduce dynamically, you can only change how you query it's results. Faceted search gives you a bit more flexibility in this scenario.

Comment: @MattWarren that's what i was seeing when I tried the example. I am having trouble implementing it however but that's another post. It appears that Faceted search is the direction that I want. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.